# Calculate Max between elemts in multiple Lists of same index in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I compare the elements of each list at the same index inside **lst** list of lists, and get the index of the sub-list according to the smallest value?

Elaboration:

```
lst = [[1,4,7] , [2,0,5] , [9,6,3]]

FirstList = []
SecondList = []
ThirdList = []

for loop to iterate over lst:
   minimum(1,2,9) -> Append 1 to FirstList.
   minimum(4,0,5) -> Append 0 to SecondList.
   minimum(7,5,3) -> Append 3 to ThirdList.
...
...
```

Comment: What is the expected output ? `[0, 1, 2]` for indices ?

Comment: Is numpy allowed or are you looking for a pure solution?

Comment: The expected output is both the indices for the lowest value in terms of lists like the answer Nk03's answer, and the element itself. And gather all "first list" in a separate list, etc.. I am looking for a pure solution without the use of any external libraries :)

Comment: Are the elements in the sublists unique? 0 is the lowest in `[0, 1, 0]`, but if such a sublist is allowed, do you want that to be added to both the first and third lists, or only one occurrence of it?

Comment: Let's say we have three different lists, and whenever we find the minimum of the three initial values, we append them according to the index of the list.

Answer (score 3):

you can try `list comprehension` with `zip` to iterate over a nested list and then you can use `min`/`index`:

```
index_list = [i.index(min(i)) for i in zip(*lst)] # prints [0, 1, 2]
```

If you need the minimum value from each sublist:

```
min_value_lst = [min(i) for i in zip(*lst)] #prints [1, 0, 3]
```

If you need them in 3 separate lists:

```
index_list = [[i.index(min(i))] for i in zip(*lst)] #prints [[0], [1], [2]]
```

Comment: One caveat is that `zip` will pack pairs over the shortest iterable. The OP hasn't explicitly stated that sublists could be of different sizes, but it might be relevant to future readers.

Comment: `Itertools.zip_longest()` is another option in that case.

Comment: Or, from Python 3.10, you can just pass `strict=True` to `zip`

Comment: With `itertools.zip_longest` you need to provide a fill value for the shorter iterables, or else it'll be None and the `min` comparison will raise an error. For min `math.inf` should suffice.

Comment: yup!!!.. We need to use the proper `fillvalue ` :) @Reti43

Comment: @Nik03 - Is there a way we can create a list of each "firstList/secondList/thirdList" in the for loop? I mean store the elements separately in three different lists. Thanks for the answer too.

Comment: Not sure what you need. But, I've updated my answer!!!. @Naz